# Conditionally replacing items in nested list based on values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Right now I have this nested list and dictionary:

```
phrases = [['Lionhearted', 'Baby Preach'], ['Lionhearted Baby', 'Preach'], ['Lionhearted', 'Baby', 'Preach']]
artist_info = {u'Baby': u'Baby by Justin Bieber', u'Lionhearted': u'Lionhearted by Porter Robinson', u'Preach': u'Preach by Drake', u'Baby Preach': u:'Baby Preach by some pop singer'}
```

Basically, what I would like to do is try to replace the values in phrases with the values from artist_info if there is a match, other wise I would like to omit that particular nested list. So since there is a dictionary entry for `'Lionhearted'`, `'Baby'`, 'baby preach' and `'Preach'`, the output would read something like this:

```
phrases2 = [['Lionhearted by Porter Robinson','Baby Preach by some pop singer'] ['Lionhearted by Porter Robinson', 'Baby by Justin Bieber', 'Preach by Drake']]
```

Is there a way to do this? I've been at this for hours. It's important that the three phrases result in the order of "Lionhearted Baby Preach". I'm a bit of a Python noob, and I haven't been able to find a comparable example.

Comment: What is this for? A media library search function?

Comment: I don't understand the correspondence. That output only seems logical for the last nested list.

Comment: What makes it decide to add, say, `'Lionhearted'` to `phrases2` rather than `'Baby'`? Is it just grabbing all matches and only keeping the unique entries?

Comment: Hey, yeah something along those lines. Sorry if I wasn't clear - yeah, I'd like to grab all of the matches between each sublist and the key in artist_info. If there's no match between that item in the sublist and the phrases2 statement, it should drop that query. Perhaps a more sensible way to phrase it would be to have artist info be artist_info = {u'Baby': u'Baby by Justin Bieber', u'Lionhearted': u'Lionhearted by Porter Robinson', u'Preach': u'Preach by Drake', u'Baby Preach': u'Baby Preach by Some Pop Singer'}. I've updated the example to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? From your example it looks like you want to omit the sublist within `phrases` if any item of that sublist is not present in the dictionary `artist_info`. The code below does that before doing the replacements you mentioned.

```
phrases = [['Lionhearted', 'Baby Preach'], ['Lionhearted Baby', 'Preach'], ['Lionhearted', 'Baby', 'Preach']]
artist_info = {u'Baby': u'Baby by Justin Bieber', u'Lionhearted': u'Lionhearted by Porter Robinson', u'Preach': u'Preach by Drake', u'Baby Preach': u'Baby Preach by some pop singer'}

lst = filter(lambda x: all(y in artist_info for y in x), phrases)
phrases2 = map(lambda x: [artist_info[y] for y in x], lst)
print phrases2
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume the sort order of the resulting list is arbitrary.

Step by step:

```
phrases = [['Lionhearted', 'Baby Preach'], ['Lionhearted Baby', 'Preach'], ['Lionhearted', 'Baby', 'Preach']]
artist_info = {u'Baby': u'Baby by Justin Bieber', u'Lionhearted': u'Lionhearted by Porter Robinson', u'Preach': u'Preach by Drake'}

phrases = [' '.join(item).split() for item in phrases]

phrases2 = set()

for item in phrases:
    for word in item:
        for key in artist_info:
            if word in artist_info.get(key):
                phrases2.add(artist_info.get(key))

phrases2 = list(phrases2)

print(*phrases2, sep='\n')
```

Or, in a comprehension:

```
phrases = [['Lionhearted', 'Baby Preach'], ['Lionhearted Baby', 'Preach'], ['Lionhearted', 'Baby', 'Preach']]
artist_info = {u'Baby': u'Baby by Justin Bieber', u'Lionhearted': u'Lionhearted by Porter Robinson', u'Preach': u'Preach by Drake'}

phrases2 = list({artist_info.get(key) for item in [' '.join(phrase).split() for phrase in phrases] for word in item for key in artist_info if word in artist_info.get(key)})
```

Content of `phrases2` with either version:

```
['Baby by Justin Bieber', 'Lionhearted by Porter Robinson', 'Preach by Drake']
```

Print this nicely with:

```
print(*phrases2, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Hey - sorry I definitely should have clarified! The order of the results is definitely pretty important (but the order of the sublists is not) - the results should be in the order Lionhearted Baby Preach. I've managed to get a version working otherwise, but the order of the words is pretty important

Comment: And what is the order? The order in which a unique value was found?

Comment: I already have my script to set up to take a string - e.g. "Lionhearted Baby Preach" and output all the possible word combinations (in the phrases list) - I need it to pull the value from the artist_info  and spit it out in the right order if there's a complete match - hopefully that makes more sense?

Comment: I recommend looking over your current script to see if you have appropriate data structures. It's quite possible that we're trying to solve an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.